# Control size change itself when i build. C#.NET WinForm DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, controls

When I build my project, a panel and a groupbox control in a form are changing!
All build action cause to this control's height increase. For example, i set the panel height as 45, then i build the project. After build, the height is 52. One more build, the damn height is 60.
Indeed there is one more form that is the same this one. But it is not changing.
How can i find what change this controls?

Comment: How can **we** find what change these controls, without knowing anything about your code.

Comment: well you right, but i did not write any code about it. It occurs on designer. So i ask that "Can any control size change itself, when the project build?"

Comment: Are you sure that they aren't in some sort of a layout container that may force the change?

Comment: yes they are in a devexpress layoutcontrol. I will try that, thank you

Comment: If you get desperate, catch the `Resize` event and set the size back to the desired size in the event handling method.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still useful to anyone.

I had the same issue, and in the end I found the problem: the control that changed its size when building had the property AutoScaleMode set to font while the main control's was set to DPI. When I changed the first one to DPI everything started to work fine. Maybe this issue is related to your final solution concerning the font change.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set auto size to the panel or groupbox.
`AutoSize = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Layoutcontrols automaticly resize your controls to fit the container. This is very nice if endusers change the size of form (maximize or sth.) because you hold a consistent look and feel. If you want to set a fix size for a control on your layoutcontrol you have to rightclick  it and say FixSize. Its same effect like you set MinimumSize and MaximumSize Properties. Then your controls cannot resize.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your care. I finally solved it. This problem is not because of DevExpress layout compenent or Form.AutoSize attribute. Actually i cant undestand how i solve exactly. I recognize that i have set Font attribute of my Form as "Verdana" instead of default value "Tahoma". Then i just reset Font attribute of my windows form. Finally, this problem (growing up itself) is solved. I cant realize how it is?!